# optimize integral f(x)exp(-x) from x=0,infinity

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods

I need a robust integration algorithm for `f(x)exp(-x)` between x=0 and infinity, with `f(x)` a positive, differentiable function.
I do not know the array `x` a priori (it's an intermediate output of my routine). The `x` array is typically ~log-equispaced, but highly irregular.
Currently, I'm using the Simpson algorithm, buy my problem is that often the domain is highly undersampled by the `x` array, which produces unrealistic values for the integral.
On each run of my code I need to do this integration thousands of times (each with a different set of x values), so I need to find an efficient and robust way to integrate this function.

More details:
The `x` array can have between 2 and N points (N known).  The first value is always `x[0] = 0.0`.  The last point is always a value greater than a tunable threshold `x_max` (such that `exp(x_max) approx 0`). I only know the values of `f` at the points `x[i]` (though the function is a smooth function).

My first idea was to do a Laguerre-Gauss quadrature integration. However, this algorithm seems to be highly unreliable when one does not use the optimal quadrature points.

My current idea is to add a set of auxiliary points, interpolating `f`, such that the Simpson algorithm becomes more stable. If I do this, is there an optimal selection of auxiliary points?

I'd appreciate any advice,
Thanks.

Comment: You might have more luck over at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: f(x)exp(x) or f(x)exp(-x)? (exponential of plus x or minus x)?

Comment: How CPU expensive is your function evaluation? (are more evaluation points cheaply affordable?)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, I meant exp(-x), sorry for the typo. I can afford to interpolate f(x), but I'm trying to avoid extra steps at all cost if possible (besides evaluating the integral so many times per run, this routine is part of a MCMC, so I run it ~10^5 times).  Thanks.

Comment: "I can afford to interpolate f(x)"... which means you can't afford to actually evaluate it? How many point do you actually have (order of magnitude if you  can't be exact)

Comment: If you really want to dive into this, I suggest looking into [Gaussian Quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature).  After you understand that you can look at [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Other_forms) to see how this applies to different intervals.  For example the problem you state would use [Gauss-Laguerre Quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature)

Comment: "highly unreliable when one does not use the optimal quadrature points": why would it work when you don't use the correct formula ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `t=1-exp(-x)`, then `dt = exp(-x) dx` and the integral value is equal to

```
integral[ f(-log(1-t)) , t=0..1 ]
```

which you can evaluate with the standard Simpson formula and hopefully get good results.

Note that piecewise linear interpolation will always result in an order 2 error for the integral, as the result amounts to a trapezoid formula even if the method was Simpson. For better errors in the Simpson method you will need higher interpolation degrees, ideally cubic splines. Cubic Bezier polynomials with estimated derivatives to compute the control points could be a fast compromise.

Comment: Thanks, I actually end up using `t=exp(-x)` and then integrated `f(t) dt`. I checked the results against analytical values, and got negligible errors. Even with a trapz algorithm, so this is much faster as well.

Comment: Yes, that works too. The difference is that one parametrization is growing, the other falling.